# Why cant i zoom in anymore into a mesh?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

creating a scene in the beginning was easy because i could zoom in all i wanted in order to do model the mesh, but after i place more objects i reach a point where it is hard to move around in the model space because it would slow down to a stop, also i cant just rotate my view and zoom into an object. I was wondering if i can change this. I've seen that by pressing "." i can zoom into the mesh, yet i would like to know if theirs another way so that i wouldn't  have to do this every time. I've also tried changing the navigation auto depth on and off in preferences. (currently using Blender 2.8)

Comment: one thing you could try is hitting shift-c.  It resets your zoom.

Comment: AFAIK there is not such a option to turn off screen focus point. Since the rotate and zooming is using a visual pivot, that's why we need to use  "." to set the looking pivot. Another better way to zoom in any thing in Blender 2.8 will be using local view("/"), it provide a better working flow.

Answer (score 1):

Hei

You can disable selection from all the things in scene. It will be easier to generally zoom in and out after this.

Answer (score 0):

Alt-middle Mouse Button re-centers the view onto whatever point you click on. If the object you're trying to zoom into dissapears, try changing the Near Clipping settings in the n-Panel> view settings tab.